# CreateWindowEx posts WM_SIZE?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

`CreateWindowEx` API really posts `WM_SIZE` message?

When I create a window via `CreateWindowEx` as **full screen mode**,

`CreateWindowEx` posts `WM_SIZE` but **window mode** doesn't.

My code sets the window style like this :

```
if(bFullscr)
{
    //When the window is in full screen mode.
    nStyle = WS_POPUP;
    nExtraStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
}
else
{
    //Otherwise.
    nStyle = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
    nExtraStyle = (WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE);
}
```

And changes display settings like this (***full screen mode only***) :

```
if(bFullscr)
{
    DEVMODE sScrSet;
    memset(&sScrSet, 0, sizeof(DEVMODE));
    sScrSet.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
    sScrSet.dmPelsWidth = nWidth;
    sScrSet.dmPelsHeight = nHeight;
    sScrSet.dmBitsPerPel = nColorBit;
    sScrSet.dmFields = (DM_BITSPERPEL | DM_PELSHEIGHT | DM_PELSWIDTH);

    if(ChangeDisplaySettings(&sScrSet, CDS_FULLSCREEN) != DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL)
    {
        //Error routine.
    }  
}
```

I'm really wonder why `CreateWindowEx` posts `WM_SIZE` message selectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to resize the window, somewhere in your code you should have `ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);` change it as follows:

```
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);//show normal
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);//show maximized (full screen)
SetWindowPos(hWnd, NULL, 10, 10, 300, 300, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);//show at specific position
```

Also you could use `WS_MAXIMIZE` in CreateWindow, but that could complicate things. Window usually has `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` or `WS_POPUP|WS_CAPTION|WS_SYSMENU`. You should pick one and keep it simple.

When Window size changes, it receives `WM_SIZE`, you can catch that and examine it.